# Are there any expansion boards available for the GPIO?

Tags: gpio, hardware

Are there any expansion boards available for the Raspberry Pi for use with the GPIO?

Comment: Do you mean a [breadboard](http://www.ladyada.net/images/arduino/halfbb.jpg)?

Comment: No, a board with level shifter for RS232 or SPI memory or a couple of I2C components something like http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard_Trainer board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/category/105) has unidirectional and bidirectional Logic Level Converters among other goodies for the RasPi.

[BitWizard](http://www.bitwizard.nl/catalog/index.php?cPath=34) B.V. also carries a range of I2C expansion boards and accessories,

Just came across this one on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQDTfZlmlq8) available [here](http://shop.openlx.org.uk/) for order(preorder)

RaspberryPI has also discussed the [Gertboard](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/tag/gertboard), but I have yet to see pricing and availability details.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the Adafruit one is interesting but has no logic on it, it is just a prototype board. 

I like the Gertboard, hope it will be available soon. 

I may just make one instead of waiting, it can be faster. But thanks a lot for the list.

Answer (score 3):

The [Pi-Face](http://piface.openlx.org.uk/) looks like a great expansion board.

From the website:

> - Allows you to control lights, motors etc and monitor digital inputs, switches, etc.
> - Four switches and four LEDs on board for rapid prototyping
> - Two onboard relays (10A) for easy control
> - Buffered to protect the Raspberry Pi; high-current open collector outputs and schmit trigger buffer inputs
> - Credit card size, stacks on top of Raspberry Pi
> - Easy to connect with screw terminals
> - Easy to program with C and Python libraries

From the looks of things this will allow you to take input from a myriad of sensors, and easily allow you to interface your Pi with external components like switches, relays, lights etc

Answer (score 1):

Seeed Studio has [Grove Base Hat for Raspberry Pi](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Base-Hat-for-Raspberry-Pi.html) which provides GPIO connectors. 
[image]

Comment: [The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, **you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)